# Converting regular color image to a blurred version

Tags: c

I'm trying to create code for converting an image into a blurred version of itself. The below code does generate a blurrier version but in my assignment's check tool I'm getting the following errors:

- blur does not filter pixels on edge
  expected "80 95 105\n", not "40 50 60\n"
- blur does not filter pixels in corner
  expected "70 85 95\n", not "10 20 30\n"
- blur does not correctly filter 3x3 image
  expected "70 85 95\n80 9..., not "10 20 30\n40 5...
- blur does not correctly filter 4x4 image
  expected "70 85 95\n80 9..., not "10 20 30\n40 5...

Since the numbers are off by so much, it doesn't seem to be a rounding issue but something completely different. Any ideas? Am I missing something basic?

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
                int sumred = 0;
                int sumgreen = 0;
                int sumblue = 0;

                for (int a = i - 1; a <= i + 1; a++)
                {
                    for (int b = j - 1; b <= j + 1; b++)
                    {
                        sumred = image[a][b].rgbtRed + sumred;
                        sumblue = image[a][b].rgbtBlue + sumblue;
                        sumgreen = image[a][b].rgbtGreen + sumgreen;
                    }
                }

                int x = round((float)sumred / 9);
                int y = round((float)sumgreen / 9);
                int z = round((float)sumblue / 9);

                image[i][j].rgbtRed = x;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = y;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = z;
        }

}
 return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a definition of blur?

Comment: In `image[i][j].rgbtRed = x;` note that i and j will be less than the heigth and width and so the last pixel (line) is not processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the posted code is probably, that it does not handle the border pixels of the input image. Take a look at the for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
        //...
```

What about the pixels for i=0 or j=0? There are different ways for handeling border pixels. The most simple way is to just consider existing pixels, e.g., for a corner pixel only consider the three neighboring pixels and divide by 4. To complete the assignment you have to know the way border pixels shall be treated.

In addition, you should create a new image. In the posted code you average averaged values. See the source code down below:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Make a copy first
    RGBTRIPLE copy_image[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                copy_image[i][j] = image[i][j];
            }
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                    float sumred = 0;
                    float sumgreen = 0;
                    float sumblue = 0;
                    int count = 0;

                    for (int a = i - 1; a <= i + 1; a++)
                    {
                        if(a > -1 && a < height) {
                            for (int b = j - 1; b <= j + 1; b++)
                            {
                                if(b > -1 && b < width) {
                                    sumred += image[a][b].rgbtRed;
                                    sumblue += image[a][b].rgbtBlue;
                                    sumgreen += image[a][b].rgbtGreen;
                                    ++count;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    copy_image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((sumred) / ((float) count));
                    copy_image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((sumgreen) / ((float) count));
                    copy_image[i][j].rgbtBlue= round((sumblue) / ((float) count));
            }
    }

    // Save the result
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                image[i][j] = copy_image[i][j];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The main (in a separate file) does take care of the creation of a new image. How would you consider the three neighboring pixels and divide by 4? As in, how do I tweak the code to accomplish that?

Comment: You may introduce a counter for the neighboring pixels within the ranges [0,width] and [0,height]. If your program creates a new image elsewhere, does it expect the result in the image array? See the source code I've submitted. I am also curious which type RGBTRIPLE is? Are these ints or floats? It would be nice to know more about your definition of blurring. Reading your posted codes indicates that (approximate) gaussian blur is used.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I got this error message:
use of undeclared identifier 'count'; did you mean 'const'?
Do I need to include a library?

Comment: No, that was my bad. I forgot to define count. I adjusted my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You *are* missing some basic things.

"Does not blur the edges" is because the loops exclude all the edge pixels. Instead, iterate every pixel, testing for and counting the pixels that are adjacent, ignoring neighbours that are "off the map." So at the corners you will average 4 pixels, dividing their sum by 4.

Besides that, you should be creating a new image, not modifying the previous one – which will give incorrect results by averaging values from those which were already averaged.

For example:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE newim[height][width], RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {   
            int sumred = 0;
            int sumgreen = 0;
            int sumblue = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int a = i - 1; a <= i + 1; a++) {
                if(a >= 0 && a < height) {
                    for (int b = j - 1; b <= j + 1; b++) {
                        if(b >= 0 && b < width) {
                            sumred   += image[a][b].rgbtRed;
                            sumblue  += image[a][b].rgbtBlue;
                            sumgreen += image[a][b].rgbtGreen;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            newim[i][j].rgbtRed   = round((float)sumred   / count);
            newim[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((float)sumgreen / count);
            newim[i][j].rgbtBlue  = round((float)sumblue  / count);
        }
    }
}
```

There could be an argument that you should "weight" the target pixels at the edges to compensate for the ones off the map, so that if there are, say, 3 pixels off the map and so can't be considered, you total `4 *` the current pixel's components and still divide by `9`. But that depends on the definition of "blurring."

Comment: Thanks Weather Vane. The creation of the new image is in a separate file, which may explain the "basic things" missing. This is only for the function of converting the image. I'm not allowed to change the top line (void blur).

Comment: The 2 basic things were a) missing all the edges, b) overwriting the data. What do you mean by "The creation of the new image is in a separate file"? You are overwriting the same array that you are analysing. It's not just the top line that you don't process, but all the edge pixels. Some of the errors posted are about edges and corners.

Comment: There is a separate file that contains "main" and "write outfile"

Comment: So? Its the *same array* that is used to analyse **and** to output. That's wrong.

Comment: In case that's still unclear, suppose a pixel's red component is `128` and the blurring changes that to `100`. Now, when you process the next pixel to its right, instead af adding `128` to the sum, you are adding `100`. On the other hand, the pixel to its right has not yet been processed and so you sum the correct value from that side.

Comment: I did try the code without the newim part, and it does output a new (blurred) file on my end, but the rightmost 1/3 was 100% black.

Comment: uh. I have `height` and `width` the wrong way round, sorry, I will correct it.

Comment: Thank you. It did rewove the black, but now it's also not making it blurry - just outputs the original. (Previously it did output a blurred version.)

Comment: Well, output the new image. The original one was not changed.

Comment: So the way this one is designed is that "main" does the outputting, and in the process calls this file for the conversion. i have multiple filters in this file, blur being one of them, and the outputting works fine as it's done in "main."

Comment: Well that's another issue. I have answered the question asked from the code posted. But the same thing will apply to all fx filters - you need an image in and an image out.

Comment: @make_flow you need access to both images at the same time - the input for calculating the average and the output for storing the result. If the function isn't passed both you'll have to make a copy.